# Java if, else statement with data

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm a beginner with programming and I'm having troubles programming a zodiac sign program. Since zodiac signs are linked with a specific data and not a month, it's more difficult to create a code. My question is: when I type in my birthday and birth month, it'll show me the wrong zodiac sign. What am I doing wrong? 
This is my code:

```
String day = DD.getText();
int dayinput;
dayinput = Integer.parseInt(day);


String month = MM.getText();
int monthinput;
monthinput = Integer.parseInt(month);

if (monthinput == 12 && dayinput <= 23 || monthinput == 1 && dayinput <= 20) {
    jLabel1.setText("Capricorn");
} else {
    jLabel1.setText("Aquarius");
}

if (monthinput == 1 && dayinput >= 21 || monthinput == 2 && dayinput <= 18) {
    jLabel1.setText("Aquarius");
} else {
    jLabel1.setText("Pisces");
}

if (monthinput == 2 && dayinput >= 19 || monthinput == 3 && dayinput <= 20) {
    jLabel1.setText("Pisces");
} else {
    jLabel1.setText("Aries");
}

if (monthinput == 3 && dayinput >= 21 || monthinput == 4 && dayinput <= 20) {
    jLabel1.setText("Aries");
} else {
    jLabel1.setText("Taurus");
}

if (monthinput == 4 && dayinput >= 21 || monthinput == 5 && dayinput <= 21) {
    jLabel1.setText("Taurus");
} else {
    jLabel1.setText("Gemini");
}

if (monthinput == 5 && dayinput >= 22 || monthinput == 6 && dayinput <= 21) {
    jLabel1.setText("Gemini");
} else {
    jLabel1.setText("Cancer");
}

if (monthinput == 6 && dayinput >= 22 || monthinput == 7 && dayinput <= 23) {
    jLabel1.setText("Cancer");
} else {
    jLabel1.setText("Leo");
}

if (monthinput == 7 && dayinput >= 24 || monthinput == 8 && dayinput <= 23) {
    jLabel1.setText("Leo");
} else {
    jLabel1.setText("Virgo");
}

if (monthinput == 8 && dayinput >= 24 || monthinput == 9 && dayinput <= 23) {
    jLabel1.setText("Virgo");
} else {
    jLabel1.setText("Libra");
}

if (monthinput == 9 && dayinput >= 24 || monthinput == 10 && dayinput <= 23) {
    jLabel1.setText("Libra");
} else {
    jLabel1.setText("Scorpio");
}

if (monthinput == 10 && dayinput >= 24 || monthinput == 11 && dayinput <= 22) {
    jLabel1.setText("Scorpio");
} else {
    jLabel1.setText("Sagittarius");
}

if (monthinput == 10 && dayinput >= 23 || monthinput == 11 && dayinput <= 22) {
    jLabel1.setText("Sagittarius");
} else {
    jLabel1.setText("Capricorn");
}
```

Comment: What does the code do? What did you expect to happen instead? Hint: your `if` blocks look odd; you probably want one `if` and many `else if`s, not starting a new `if` so often. Step through the program in a debugger and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Could you show more of your code? where is the jLabel initialized, also I wouldn't make each case a new if statement

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, to get better help please read [mcve]

Comment: I was expecting that if my input was day= 6 and month=10, it'll show me the zodiac sign libra, but now I'm getting Capricorn as the output

Comment: Your first `if` statement is wrong. It says Capricorn is `dayInput <= 23` in December. Then after that, your `if else` structure doesn't make sense. The result will always be Capricorn if it is not Sagittarius. That is what `else` does.

Comment: Yes, that's because <23 would be Sagittarius. That's what I mean with the dayinput <= 23

Comment: SUGGESTION: 1) Put your Zodiac symbols into a string array: `String[] zodiac = {"Cancer", "Leo", "Virgo", ...}.  2) Write a simple expression that computes an index (0, 1, 2, ...,11) from [Calendar day-of-year](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), 3) use the index value to get the Zodiac text for your jLabel1 object.  Your code should shrink by about 30 lines or so ;)

Comment: I would recommend parenthesizing your boolean expressions. It's hard to tell whether you mean `monthinput == 12 && (dayinput <= 23 || monthinput == 1) && dayinput <= 20` or `(monthinput == 12 && dayinput <= 23) || (monthinput == 1 && dayinput <= 20)`.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I look at your problem and as `reviewer` it was easier for me to write more readable code than find a bug within multiple `if...else`.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    int day = Integer.parseInt(DD.getText());
    int month = Integer.parseInt(MM.getText());
    ZodiacSign zodiacSign = ZodiacSign.get(day, month);
    JLabel jLabel1 = new JLabel(zodiacSign.name());
    System.out.println(jLabel1.getText());
}

public enum ZodiacSign {
    Aries(21, Calendar.MARCH, 20, Calendar.APRIL),
    Taurus(21, Calendar.APRIL, 21, Calendar.MAY),
    Gemini(22, Calendar.MAY, 21, Calendar.JUNE),
    Cancer(22, Calendar.JUNE, 22, Calendar.JULY),
    Leo(21, Calendar.JULY, 21, Calendar.AUGUST),
    Virgo(22, Calendar.AUGUST, 23, Calendar.SEPTEMBER),
    Libra(24, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 23, Calendar.OCTOBER),
    Scorpio(24, Calendar.OCTOBER, 22, Calendar.NOVEMBER),
    Sagittarius(23, Calendar.NOVEMBER, 22, Calendar.DECEMBER),
    Capricorn(23, Calendar.DECEMBER, 20, Calendar.JANUARY),
    Aquarius(21, Calendar.JANUARY, 19, Calendar.FEBRUARY),
    Pisces(20, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 20, Calendar.MARCH);

    private final int dayFrom;
    private final int dayTo;
    private final int monthFrom;
    private final int monthTo;

    ZodiacSign(int dayFrom, int monthFrom, int dayTo, int monthTo) {
        this.dayFrom = dayFrom;
        this.monthFrom = monthFrom + 1;
        this.dayTo = dayTo;
        this.monthTo = monthTo + 1;
    }

    public static ZodiacSign get(int day, int month) {
        for (ZodiacSign sign : values())
            if (month == sign.monthFrom && day >= sign.dayFrom
                    || month == sign.monthTo && day <= sign.dayTo)
                return sign;

        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot select ZodiacSign");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

dayinput <= 23 is wrong, capricorn is >= 22

```
if  (monthinput == 12 && dayinput <= 23 || monthinput == 1 && dayinput <= 20 ) 
{
        jLabel1.setText("Capricorn");
```

check the rest of sign, the else statement is wrong in every case, substitute with another if statement.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that almost always the last else is executed.
Use an if-then-else-if chain to have exclusive cases.

```
    String sign;
    if (month == 12 && day <= 23 || month == 1 && day <= 20) {
        sign = "Capricorn";
    } else if (month == 1 && day >= 21 || month == 2 && day <= 18) {
         sign = "Aquarius";
    } else if (month == 2 && day >= 19 || month == 3 && day <=20) {
         sign = "Pisces";
    } else if (month == 3 && day >= 21 || month == 4 && day <=20) {
         sign = "Aries";
    } else if (month == 4 && day >= 21 || month == 5 && day <= 21) {
         sign = "Taurus";
    } else if (month == 5 && day >= 22 || month == 6 && day <= 21) {
         sign = "Gemini";
    } else if (month == 6 && day >= 22 || month == 7 &&  day <= 23) {
        sign = "Cancer";
    } else if (month == 7 && day >= 24 || month == 8 && day <= 23) {
         sign = "Leo";
    } else if (month == 8 && day >= 24 || month == 9 && day <=23) {
         sign = "Virgo";
    } else if (month == 9 && day >= 24 || month == 10 && day <=23) {
         sign = "Libra";
    } else if (month == 10 && day >= 24 || month == 11 && day <=22) {
         sign = "Scorpio";
    } else if (month == 10 && day >= 23 || month == 11 && day <=22) {
         sign = "Sagittarius";
    } else {
         sign = "Capricorn";
    }
    jLabel1.setText(sign);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

- zodiac sign have range - make every range something like a step with a start "date".
- go through the steps - I find it easyer to go from the upper to the lower bound. If you haven't passed the "date" of one step, you are in the range of this step.

Hope this make it clear.

```
enum ZodiacSign { Aquarius, Pisces, Aries, Taurus, Gemini, Cancer, Leo, Virgo, Libra, Scorpio, Sagittarius, Capricorn }

public String GetZodiacSign(int month, int day)
{
    Map<Integer,ZodiacSign>m = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,ZodiacSign>();

    m.put(1222,ZodiacSign.Capricorn);
    m.put(1122,ZodiacSign.Sagittarius);
    m.put(1023,ZodiacSign.Scorpio);
    m.put(923 ,ZodiacSign.Libra);
    m.put(823 ,ZodiacSign.Virgo);
    m.put(723 ,ZodiacSign.Leo); 
    m.put(621 ,ZodiacSign.Cancer);
    m.put(520 ,ZodiacSign.Gemini);
    m.put(420 ,ZodiacSign.Taurus);
    m.put(321 ,ZodiacSign.Aries);
    m.put(219 ,ZodiacSign.Pisces);
    m.put(120 ,ZodiacSign.Aquarius);
    m.put(101 ,ZodiacSign.Capricorn); // loop back

    int position = month * 100 + day;

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, ZodiacSign> entry : m.entrySet())
    {
        if (position > entry.getKey()) { return entry.getValue().toString(); }
    }
}
```